# Executing SQL scripts on docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker container running mysql and I want to push a .sql file to the container and then have mysql execute the commands in it.  The first step is fairly straightforward:

```
docker cp ./dummy.sql <container_id>:/
```

From there I am trying to run mysql from the command line and point it to the file that I just pushed to the container.

```
docker exec <container_id> mysql -u root -ppassword < /dummy.sql
```

This command appears to be trying to use /sample.sql as stdin locally rather than on the container.  I also tried wrapping quotes around everything after the container ID which also seems to not work.

I also tried pushing a .sh file with the command in it to the docker container and then just executing that, but that is less ideal and also not working.  Any advice?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are going to do pipe redirections in your command, pass it as a string to `/bin/sh`:

```
docker exec <container_id> /bin/sh -c 'mysql -u root -ppassword </dummy.sql'
```

Answer (score 33):

One does not need to copy the script first. If the script is on the host then:

```sh
docker exec -i <container_name> mysql -u root -ppassword <mydb> < /path/to/script.sql
```

Or if the Use db directive is contained inside the script:

```sh
docker exec -i <container_name> mysql -u root -ppassword < /path/to/script.sql
```

Comment: You don't need to use `-e` or `cat`. You can simply use `docker exec -i <container_name> mysql -u root -ppassword < /path/to/script.sql`, assuming that the script is on the host.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
docker exec <container_id> 'mysql -u root -ppassword </dummy.sql'
```

Comment: I mentioned trying that except I used double quotes rather than single.  I'll try single quotes when I can.  When I did that,  it seems like docker was trying to execute the entire string as one  literal command for some reason.

Comment: @Akron if there are no quotes, bash will interpret string first (and pass dummy to stdio) before calling docker.