# Docker: launch a mssql script outside of the docker image

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I've been trying to run an MSSQL script on my docker and it always fails... is my syntax wrong or something... I've looked this post but it doesn't work
[Executing SQL scripts on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779894/executing-sql-scripts-on-docker-container)

```
docker exec mssql '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P gitgood12345 -q </CRE.sql'
```

this returned an error

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ************** -q </CRE.sql\": stat /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P AucMa1633485 -q </CRE.sql: no such file or directory"
```

I also tried something like this...

```
sudo docker exec -it mssql /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'gitgood12345' -q </CRE.sql
```

The command returns me this error, which I'm not sure why....

```
Sqlcmd: '-q': Missing argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

Please help me... the second method used to work, I think I forget a parameter or something...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`sqlcmd` `-q`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) option requires an argument of the command you want to run. As your example is piping commands in on standard input, try without the `-q`.

```
docker exec mssql /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P gitgood12345 < /CRE.sql
```

Quoting everything results in the container trying to execute a binary named `"/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P gitgood12345 -q </CRE.sql"` which doesn't exist.