# Execute tests in mysql docker container and exit

Tags: mysql, docker

I cannot figure out how to fully start [ubuntu/mysql](https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/mysql), prepare the db, execute tests, and exit the container. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu/mysql:latest
COPY my_db_scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY my_test.sh /tests
WORKDIR /tests
```

I am running it with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=cool my_tests:1.0.0
```

The **my_db_scripts.sql** completes successfully. However, if I add **my_tests.sh** as an ENTRYPOINT or CMD at the end of the Dockerfile, the test scripts execute **before** mysql listener starts. If I add **my_tests.sh** to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/, the script executes after the temp mysql instance stops, as quoted in the documentation:

> All of this is done before the MySQL service is started. Keep in mind if your database directory is not empty (contains pre-existing database) they will be left untouched.

How can I wait for mysql to start, execute **my_tests.sh**, and stop the container? ( i.e my test scripts will return error or no error based on results )

Links I used to try different things:

[Executing SQL scripts on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779894/executing-sql-scripts-on-docker-container)

[How do I know when my docker mysql container is up and mysql is ready for taking queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503412/how-do-i-know-when-my-docker-mysql-container-is-up-and-mysql-is-ready-for-taking)

[How to add a startup script to a mysql docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482257/how-to-add-a-startup-script-to-a-mysql-docker-container)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to run the tests from inside the database?  Can you start an unmodified database container, then run the tests from outside the container?

Comment: the container will be configured with many other utilities that i would rather not put on the host. ( the tests depend on them ) i look at the container as a replicated dev env that is decoupled from the one executing it ( me, jenkins , etc )

Comment: I'd still set this up as two containers, one running the database proper (an unmodified `mysql` container) and a second running the tests (from your CI pipeline, with the image-of-tools).

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the suggestion. for the time being, i'd like to experiment with this approach.